# Remove dud tags?

Tags: discussion

I think the [aztec](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aztec) tag should be removed as it's way too specific, unlikely for Worldbuilding use, ans only used on one question.

But I don't see a button for that, or any way to submit it for attention.

Comment: It's not really hurting anyone. You could just remove it from the one question that uses it, and it'd be like it doesn't even exist.

Comment: It would still be there for people to choose. I think our tag wiki needs a bit of a cleanup.

Comment: Similar previous discussion:  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2095/2113

Answer (score 1):

Tags are removed automatically after a period of time where they don't have at least two questions using them.  I forget how long.  Six months maybe?

> It would still be there for people to choose.

Only very new posters can't create tags for themselves.  The only real difference is that it will show up if someone types "tec" and notices it before the fourth letter (or az.. or zt... but no one seems to be typing those).  So someone who is typing technology might see it.  But how many people type technology on a question about Aztecs?  If there are a lot of people doing this, maybe we do want the tag.

The tag system is designed to be mostly self-maintaining.  People add tags as needed; the system prunes unneeded tags.  Sometimes people create a tag that a moderator removes.  These tend to be not over-specific tags but over-general ones.  For example, a tag for [worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding) wouldn't be much use here.  Outside of that though, manually mucking with the tag hierarchy is extra work that doesn't really give us anything.  The automatic pruning will handle truly over-specific tags.  Eventually.

Comment: A tag with *zero* questions, or one question and no tag wiki, is auto-deleted after a day or two.  A tag with two or more questions, or one question and a tag wiki, is safe.